# There is a billing page that I fill in all the details and click on make bill button, then the invoice page should be generated

Tags: python, django

There is a billing page that I fill in all the details and click on make bill button, then the invoice page should be generated, it is not coming.

views.py

```
def makebill(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        cart = request.POST.get('cart')
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        n = request.POST.get('name')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        data = json.loads(cart)
        for c in data:
            name = c['name']
            qty = c['qty']
            prod = Product.objects.get(name=name)
            prod.qty = prod.qty - int(qty)
            if prod.qty <= 0:
                messages.warning(request, f'{prod.name} has finished')
                prod.delete()
            else:
                prod.save()
        p= Sales(items_json=cart, amount=price, name=n, phone=phone)
        p.save()
        total = price
        product = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
        product_list = list(product.values('name', 'cost'))
        context = {}
        context["product"] = json.dumps(product_list)
        try:
            context["total"] = total
        except:
            pass
        return render(request, 'makebill.html', context)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is page not coming? What's the error that you get? Is it HTTP 500 or something else? Please give more detail about the problem. Also your code's indent is not looking ok. Be careful, last 9 lines are outside of the post request.

Comment: I am not getting any error whenever I fill that form and click on make bill then I am redirected to that same page. instead of redirect to the same page, I want to redirect to an invoice page.

Comment: Is indent of the code ok? It doesn't look like it is. Last 9 lines should be indented. If it just look like this on your post but your code is correct, fix it also here because it's confusing. Also still not helping with the error. Did your backend get the request from frontend? What did it return?

Comment: If I indented the code this error is showing "The view home.views.makebill didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."